# how do you call shell scripts from an arbitrary directory?

Tags: shell, terminal

I am setting up a shell script to run with cron, but i have an issue getting to the file.  When using cron, i can run 1 thing, it was the line:

```
php /home/testfile.php >> /home/logFile.txt
```

but it has issues when referencing files... as the current working directory is not actually in /home/

I was trying to get a small shell script together to do what i wanted, but that is located in /home/

```
export UPD_SCRIPT=/home/
pushd .
cd $UPD_SCRIPT
php testfile.php >> logfile.txt
popd
```

but now i need to get to it with cron, and i dont know how to reference it.  I tried:

```
. .//home/myscript.sh
```

and similar things, but it did not work.

How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crontab, simply use:

```
(cd /home && php /home/testfile.php >> /home/logFile.txt)
```

As for referencing your own script with cron, just use its path, like so:

```
* * * * * /home/myscript.sh
```

Remember to set the executable bit first with

```
chmod +x /home/myscript.sh
```

Comment: so, it will auto just run the script?  I was thinking that i would need some commands to tell it to execute the script.  Thanks.

Comment: If it's executable, then yes, it should.